# Maven-Dependency-Plugin: NoSuchElementException for Aether RepositorySystem

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I keep seeing a NoSuchElementException for the  tag in the maven-dependency-plugin. I have tried adding dependencies for aether-spi, aether-api, and aether-util to my pom.xml but the error does not go away. I can sometimes get it to go away if I repeatedly update and clean the project or run mvn package. Is there a dependency I can add or an update to the plugin I can make to prevent this error? Is there something wrong with my pom.xml?

I am using eclipse Mars 4.5.2 and Maven 3.2.3.

Here is the error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem
  roleHint:  (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy-dependencies:copy-dependencies:package)

org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem
  roleHint: 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
    at com.coderplus.utils.BuildHelper.<init>(BuildHelper.java:159)
    at com.ianbrandt.tools.m2e.mdp.core.MdpBuildParticipant.build(MdpBuildParticipant.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    ... 28 more
```

Here is my plugin from the pom.xml:

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**EDIT**: Here is the full pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.company.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyService</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MyService</name>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Jetty Setup -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.my.company.MyApp</mainClass>
                    <classpathScope>runtime</classpathScope>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webDefaultXml>${project.basedir}/conf/jetty/webdefault.xml</webDefaultXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jetty Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON processing: jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Base64 encoding that works in both JVM and Android -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.brsanthu</groupId>
            <artifactId>migbase64</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Aether dependencies to fix error on maven-dependency-plugin execution -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
            <artifactId>aether-spi</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.aether</groupId>
            <artifactId>aether-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.aether</groupId>
            <artifactId>aether-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey-version>1.19.1</jersey-version>
        <jersey2-version>2.22.1</jersey2-version>
        <jackson-version>2.4.2</jackson-version>
        <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
        <maven-plugin-version>1.0.0</maven-plugin-version>
        <commons-lang-version>3.4</commons-lang-version>
        <slf4j-version>1.7.21</slf4j-version>
        <jetty-version>9.3.6.v20151106</jetty-version>
        <coverage.complexity.minimum>0</coverage.complexity.minimum>
        <coverage.line.minimum>0</coverage.line.minimum>
        <coverage.missed.classes>0</coverage.missed.classes>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post the full pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise see edited question

Comment: Do you like to produce a war or jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using **Maven3**, you need to add the **maven-resolver-api** version **1.4.1** as dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resolver-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If anybody stumbles in this issue and is using **Maven2**, please add the same dependency, but use version **1.3.1**

Answer (score -3):

First you have defined packaging `jar` but you have define the maven-war-plugin in your pom file? If you like to produce a war file change the packaging to `war`. Furthermore I'm not sure why you are using maven-dependency-plugin to copy file to lib folder? This looks wrong. Furthermore dependencies to Aether is simply wrong, cause it's used by Maven and plugins but usually not by users...

Comment: I added the Aether dependencies in an attempt to get rid of the error I'm seeing.  Can you be more specific on what I should do to fix the pom? I'm working off of an existing pom.xml file so I'm not sure what all the reasons for adding the plugins were. I want to produce a jar. Are you suggesting I remove the maven-war-plugin?

Comment: If you create a jar than maven-war-plugin does not make sense. Furthermore I don`t understand the usage of maven-dependency-plugin:copy apart from that remove those aether deps..

Comment: From reading about it on the swagger-maven-plugin website. Copy-dependencies is a "goal that copies the project dependencies from the repository to a defined location." So, in my case I think it is copying the dependencies to the target directory. Would you recommend a different plugin or an alternate method to copy the files?